How to automatically add data-testid to all UI elements of an angular application
I am working on a angular project having thousands of html files. Now we are trying to implement UI test automation using cypress. However, we are facing some difficulties in uniquely identify UI elements in cypress. Adding data-testid to all UI elements will resolve this issue. but manually adding data-testid to all UI elements will be a time consuming task.
I am looking for a solution to automatically add a unique data-testid to all UI elements by combining context_name_element_id.
Any help would be appreciated.
Expecting an easy  solution to automatically add data-testid to all UI elements in angular application automatically.

IMO, I would avoid doing something like this automatically since only a fraction of those elements would ever be used by the testing system. But you will have increased the size of the app's pages significantly in the process.

There are other ways to tackle the issue, for example if you already have aria attributes in the app they can serve the same purpose as data-testid attributes.

totally agree with @Minchin as it clogs your html files completely and it also wouldnt truly know what each element does so it wouldn't be clear for whoever writes the tests what each object is and you'd instead just have a bunch of cryptic IDs. adding each data-testid for the single object needed while writing the tests seems like the best solution. I'd also suggest not using random id's but short names like 'login-btn', 'agree-checkbox',...
